# One of the Navigation Link to be made invisible for a User Group -Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a link called Create Reimbursemtn in the Quick Launch Menu. I dont want this link visible to certain group of users.

I am using Sharepoint 2010. I don't have any audience settings in the Navigation settins. Am i missing something? Can this be done out of box or programmatically ? Please let me know how can I achieve this requirement. Its urgent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup `User Profile Service application` for the Audience feature to be visible.